# Transpose groups/subgroups in sql oracle

Tags: sql

I have date column which i have to divide in 6 quarters and calculate count,ratio- A/Count, Avg(colC) by State. Date column i have converted to YYYY Q format.  I was wondering if i can get results shown below. i am using oracle 11g. I am just trying to write a sql which can give me results in above format. I am able to Group results in quarter but unable to further subgroup it to show count,Ratio and Avg under each quarter. –

I have 2 tables that i need to use to get data below.

```
Table 1                                     Table 2

Customer_id    St_Nme      St_Cd           Customer_id  No_of_sales  Time_spent  Date
    1          Alabama     AL                  1           4           4.5       01122012
    2          California  CA                  2           7.5         9.33      03062012
```

Desired Output
                 Count-Count of sales
                 Ratio-Time_spent/Count of sales
                 Avg - Average of time spent

```
            Q42012         Q32012          Q22012             Q12012    Q42011   Q32012  
         count Ratio Avg  count Ratio Avg   count Ratio Avg
State       
Alabama    3    4.5  1.2    8  7.4    3.2    65   21.1  34.4
A..        4    7.5  3.2    5  9.4    5.2    61   25.1  39.4
A..        9    6.5  5.2    4  3.4    3.7    54   41.1  44.4
Boston
Cali..
Den..
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to answer your question. I'm not even sure what you're asking. And you want to divide something into 6 quarters?

Comment: I am just trying to write a sql which can give me results in above format. I am able to Group results in quarter but unable to further subgroup it to show count,Ratio and Avg under each quarter.

Comment: @user1742716 please post the table structures, you current queries and some sample data.  It is difficult to determine based on the final result as it is just part of the picture. But you _might_ be able to do this with the `PIVOT` function

Comment: Off topic... but when did Boston & Denver become states?